# Why does Docker require PATH when building from custom Dockerfile in another directory?

Tags: docker

When building docker images with a `Dockerfile` in the same directory, the following works every time

```
$ docker build -t project/app:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  135.9MB
...
```

However, when using `-f` to specify a different Dockerfile to use, docker complains ...

```
$ docker build -t project/app:latest -f ../some/path/Dockerfile.other 
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

I can easily provide the `PATH`, and the build will work, but why is the `PATH` still required if I'm specifying the absolute path to the `Dockerfile` with `-f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` is for specifying the build context (the tree from which `COPY` instructions copy things), which need not have any relation to the location of the Dockerfile.

[Quoting the docs:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description)

> The `docker build` command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified `PATH` or `URL`. The build process can refer to any of the files in the context. For example, your build can use a `COPY` instruction to reference a file in the context.

Comment: Makes sense - Thanks for responding!